# list python packages consumed by an application

Tags: python

```
def get_pkgs():
    pkgs = []
    for importer, modname, ispkg in \
            pkgutil.walk_packages(path=None, onerror=lambda x: None):
    pkgs.append(modname)
    return pkgs
```

Above code snippet gives me all python packages in distribution. Can someone suggest me a way to get all packages out of these used by a python application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/) is nice, as already answered by Sven Marnach, but this gives all file dependencies and I'm not sure if it will just tell you what packages are used, versus every single file dependency.

For packages available in the [Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi), you could use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) (and [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/), which comes with it) to get a simple list of required/used packages.

For example, assuming you also have the excellent [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/pythonmagazine/completely-different/2008-05-virtualenvwrapper/index.html) tools installed (*highly* recommended), below is a sequence that shows what the package requirements are for [pylint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint):

```
$ mkvirtualenv pylint_dep_check --no-site-packages
New python executable in pylint_dep_check/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
$ pip freeze   #Note the wsgiref 'bug' where it always shows up
wsgiref==0.1.2
$ workon pylint_dep_check
(pylint_dep_check) $ pip install pylint
(... snipped lengthy install text ...)
(pylint_dep_check) $ pip freeze
logilab-astng==0.21.1
logilab-common==0.55.0
pylint==0.23.0
unittest2==0.5.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Noe the all-important use of the `--no-site-packages` virtualenv creation option which (surprise!) ensures that your virtualenv is completely fresh and has none of the site-packages from your distribution installed.  This way it is clear what is needed for the app you installed.

If this is an application that you have developed, a nice way to keep track of your dependencies (and an excellent/clean way to work) is to set up the application in a clean [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi) (created using the `--no-site-packages` option again) and then again use `pip freeze` to figure out what packages you've installed to make it work.

The ability to start a "fresh" python installation with the `--no-site-packages` option is *extremely* useful.  I do it for all applications and to test out packages I'm interested in without cluttering my workspace(s).

If you aren't using virtualenv and pip yet, get on it already.  Here is a good introduction:
http://mathematism.com/2009/07/30/presentation-pip-and-virtualenv/

Comment: The code the OP posted also lists every single file, not only packages, so I expected this is what the OP wants.

Comment: No, I wanted to get all packages which are being imported by files in a python application. For example Project A has x, y & z as its files. if x imports I1, I2, I3; y imports J1, J2; and z imports I1, J2, K1. I want a list: I1, I2, I3, J1, J2, K1.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the Python dependency analysis tool [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/).