# Get a list of python packages used by a Django Project

Tags: python, django

Is there any easy way to get a list of python packages used by a Django project?

I've looked at snakefood and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219711/list-python-packages-consumed-by-an-application), but neither seem to play nicely within the django environment.

Ideally I'm looking for a command I can execute from the python shell or from bash to list all of the pypy supported dependencies that aren't native to django.

Comment: grep import -r /path/to/your/django/project

Comment: @TomO'Connor I had tried grep but couldn't figure out how to get it refined enough so that it was just printing out my import statements. And even then it would still be a pain to sort through all that and figure out which are the actual non-native packages

Comment: `grep import ...` is not enough. How about those imported using `from x import y`? Then there's also apps loaded from settings.INSTALLED_APPS (and their dependencies) which may be external to a django project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer but hopefully it'll make a sensible starting point.

From what I can tell, the dependencies of a django project (apart from django itself and its dependencies`*`) consists of:

1. Modules imported by your django project
2. Apps loaded by your project via `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` (and their dependencies)

#### #1  Modules imported by your project

You can probably discover this using [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/).

#### #2 Apps loaded via `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`

Running the following script should give the path to apps listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from settings import INSTALLED_APPS
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
import os

app_names = (x for x in INSTALLED_APPS if not x.startswith('django'))
app_paths = (os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(import_module(x).__file__)) for x in app_names)    
print "\n".join(x for x in app_paths if not x.startswith(os.getcwd()))
```

You can then pass this on to `snakefood` to discover their dependencies.

---

`*` To be thorough, it should be possible to discover the various backends (db/cache/auth/etc.) from `settings` and include the associated modules into your list of dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this is useful, in case the project used 'pip' to install the dependencies/libraries:

```
pip freeze
```

Comment: This will just show you what's installed, not what's being *used*. Particularly problematic if you're using an environment shared between multiple projects.

Answer (score 3):

run this command inside your django project, this will write all the installed packages inside requirements.txt file

```
 pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

or if you are using python3 then use pip3 like this

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

you will find the requirements.txt file inside your django project

Comment: You're assuming that a virtualenv is being used. If that's not the case, this will write all system installed packages, which may not be what the user wants.

Answer (score 2):

[pigar](https://github.com/damnever/pigar) works fine for me.

It doesn't cover INSTALLED_APPS [yet](https://github.com/damnever/pigar/issues/33), but that's just a little extra work.