# List dependencies in Python

Tags: python

What is the most efficient way to list all dependencies required to deploy a working project elsewhere (on a different OS, say)?

Python 2.7, Windows dev environment, not using a virtualenv per project, but a global dev environment, installing libraries as needed, happily hopping from one project to the next.

I've kept track of most (not sure *all*) libraries I had to install for a given project. I have *not* kept track of any sub-dependencies that came auto-installed with them. Doing `pip freeze` lists both, plus all the other libraries that were ever installed.

Is there a way to list what you need to install, no more, no less, to deploy the project?

**EDIT** In view of the answers below, some clarification. My project consists of a bunch of modules (that I wrote), each with a bunch of `import`s. Should I just copy-paste all the imports from all modules into a single file, sort eliminating duplicates, and throw out all from the standard library (and how do I know they are)? Or is there a better way? That's the question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Scan your `import` statements. Chances are you only import things you explicitly wanted to import, and not the dependencies.

Make a list like the one `pip freeze` does, then create and activate a virtualenv.

Do `pip install -r your_list`, and try to run your code in that virtualenv. Heed any `ImportError` exceptions, match them to packages, and add to your list. Repeat until your code runs without problems.

Now you have a list to feed to `pip install` on your deployment site.

This is extremely manual, but requires no external tools, and forces you to make sure that your code runs. (Running your test suite as a check is great but not sufficient.)

Comment: This answer is correct, and is nice in that it doesn't depend on any tools. Check out some of the other answers for ways to scan your imports automatically.

Comment: @nighthawk454: Thank you. I've upvoted these other answers.

Comment: With currently so many tools and none that do a good job, this might actually end up being the fastest and easiest answer.

Answer (score 166):

`pipreqs` solves the problem. It generates ***project-level*** requirement.txt file.

Install pipreqs: `pip install pipreqs`

1. Generate project-level requirement.txt file: `pipreqs /path/to/your/project/`
2. requirements file would be saved in /path/to/your/project/requirements.txt

If you want to read more advantages of `pipreqs` over `pip freeze`, read it [from here](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs)

Comment: @wim Thanks for your comment.  For production, I agree `setup.py` is a better choice. for dev purpose, I recommend using `requirement.txt` to pin the pkg versions for the dev environment

Comment: The question asks **list all dependencies required to deploy a working project**.  Later it asked "Is there a way to list what you need to install, **no more**, no less, to deploy the project?". That's clearly asking about production, and not about development!  I also recommend using `requirement.txt` to pin the pkg versions for the dev environment - but it's not what the question is about.

Comment: I guess this is what you're referring to: https://packaging.python.org/requirements/

Comment: @nighthawk454  Yes, exactly

Comment: `pipreqs` does not work for me.  I have a script that imports pdfminer (`from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage`) yet requirement,.txt remains empty; pdfminer should be listed.

Comment: i'm working with django deployed on heroku, and tried creating a requirements.txt using pipreqs, and encountered some errors. from what i've learned, pipreqs gathers the dependencies that were imported in the python scripts within a django project dir, but not considering the applications stated in settings.INSTALLED_APPS (i.e. django crispy forms).

Comment: The problem is that it fails on python 2 files... (Installed it with Python 3)

Comment: @R.Karlus what error did you get, I use it in my python2.7 and python3.5 projects

Comment: Unfortunately, pipreqs has some "stupid" bugs, like for mysql-connector or hydra

Comment: `pipreqs` will miss packages actually used by the project (e.g. gunicorn), and add packages that don't make sense because they're not used and do not even exist (e.g. `en_core_web_sm==3.5.0`, `python_bcrypt==0.3.2`.)

Answer (score 13):

On your terminal type:

```
pip install pipdeptree
cd <your project root>
pipdeptree
```

Comment: `pipdeptree` is a powerful tool that does what you are saying. In its [README](https://github.com/naiquevin/pipdeptree#using-pipdeptree-to-write-requirementstxt-file) it tells you how to get just the higher level dependencies. Steps:
1) Create a virtual environment. 
2) Attempt to run the program. Install the dependencies it expects as it errors.
3) Then use `pipdeptree` command in the linked Readme to get the minimum requirements.

Comment: I get the same output no matter what folder i'm in. this makes me think it does not consider the modules but is just reading what's installed in pip.

Comment: It respects the deepest level of directory to check for the dependencies. If you are out of an venv then it will take from global installation.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use **pipreqs**, install it using:

```
pip install pipreqs
```

Then, type: `pipreqs .` on the files directory.
A text file named requirements will be created for you, which looks like this:

```
numpy==1.21.1
pytest==6.2.4
matplotlib==3.4.2
PySide2==5.15.2
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [findpydeps](https://pypi.org/project/findpydeps/) module I wrote:

- Install it via pip: `pip install findpydeps`
- If you have a main file: `findpydeps -l -i path/to/main.py` (the `-l` will *follow* the imports in the file)
- Or your code is in a folder: `findpydeps -i path/to/folder`
- Most importantly, the output is pip-friendly:

  - do `findpydeps -i . > requirements.txt` (assuming `.` is your project's directory)
  - then `pip install -r requirements.txt`

You can of course search through multiple directories and files for requirements, like: `findpydeps -i path/to/file1.py path/to/folder path/to/file2.py`, etc.

By default, it will remove the packages that are in the python standard library, as well as local packages. Refer to the `-r`/`--removal-policy` argument for more info.

If you don't want imports that are done in **if**, **try/except** or **with** blocks, just add `--no-blocks`. The same goes for **functions** with `--no-functions`.

Anyway, you got the idea: there are a lot of options (most of them are not discussed here). Refer the `findpydeps -h` output for more help!

Comment: Top tool, from what I can tell other pip modules don't list imported python files. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answers here didn't work too well for me as I only wanted the imports from inside our repository (eg. `import requests` I don't need, but `from my.module.x import y` I do need).

I noticed that `PyInstaller` had perfectly good functionality for this though. I did a bit of digging and managed to find their dependency graph code, then just created a function to do what I wanted with a bit of trial and error. I made a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/huntfx/65641778c4d14e513a92696017f1823f) since I'll likely need it again in the future, but here is the code:

```
import os

from PyInstaller.depend.analysis import initialize_modgraph


def get_import_dependencies(*scripts):
    """Get a list of all imports required.
    Args: script filenames.
    Returns: list of imports
    """
    script_nodes = []
    scripts = set(map(os.path.abspath, scripts))

    # Process the scripts and build the map of imports
    graph = initialize_modgraph()
    for script in scripts:
        graph.run_script(script)
    for node in graph.nodes():
        if node.filename in scripts:
            script_nodes.append(node)

    # Search the imports to find what is in use
    dependency_nodes = set()
    def search_dependencies(node):
        for reference in graph.getReferences(node):
            if reference not in dependency_nodes:
                dependency_nodes.add(reference)
                search_dependencies(reference)
    for script_node in script_nodes:
        search_dependencies(script_node)

    return list(sorted(dependency_nodes))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Show the PyInstaller imports used in this file
    for node in get_import_dependencies(__file__):
        if node.identifier.split('.')[0] == 'PyInstaller':
            print(node)
```

All the node types are defined in `PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph.modulegraph`, such as `SourceModule`, `MissingModule`, `Package` and `BuiltinModule`. These will come in useful when performing checks.

Each of these has an `identifier` (`path.to.my.module`), and depending on the node type, it may have a `filename` (`C:/path/to/my/module/__init__.py`), and `packagepath` (`['C:/path/to/my/module']`).

I can't really post any extra code as it is quite specific to our setup with using `pyarmor` with `PyInstaller`, I can happily say it works flawlessly so far though.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is analyze your imports. To automate that, check out [Snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/). Then you can make a `requirements.txt` file and get on your way to using `virtualenv`.

The following will list the dependencies, excluding modules from the standard library:

```
sfood -fuq package.py | sfood-filter-stdlib | sfood-target-files
```

Related questions:

[Get a list of python packages used by a Django Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170914/get-a-list-of-python-packages-used-by-a-django-project)

[list python package dependencies without loading them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875232/list-python-package-dependencies-without-loading-them)

Comment: Snakefood just generates dependency graphs.  How do you propose to exclude the test dependencies and the dependencies-of-dependencies?

Comment: This does not work on Python3 and the author notes in the README that porting it does require quite some work. It still uses the old compile/compile.ast modules which have been removed on Python3. Analysing Python3 packages fails for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an Anaconda virtual environment, you can run the below command inside the environment to create a txt file of all the dependencies used in the project.

```
conda list -e > requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just run something like this:

```
import importlib
import os
import pathlib
import re
import sys, chardet
from sty import fg

sys.setrecursionlimit(100000000)

dependenciesPaths = list()
dependenciesNames = list()
paths = sys.path
red = fg(255, 0, 0)
green = fg(0, 200, 0)
end = fg.rs


def main(path):
    try:
        print("Finding imports in '" + path + "':")

        file = open(path)
        contents = file.read()
        wordArray = re.split(" |\n", contents)

        currentList = list()
        nextPaths = list()
        skipWord = -1

        for wordNumb in range(len(wordArray)):
            word = wordArray[wordNumb]

            if wordNumb == skipWord:
                continue

            elif word == "from":
                currentList.append(wordArray[wordNumb + 1])
                skipWord = wordNumb + 2

            elif word == "import":
                currentList.append(wordArray[wordNumb + 1])

        currentList = set(currentList)
        for i in currentList:
            print(i)

        print("Found imports in '" + path + "'")
        print("Finding paths for imports in '" + path + "':")

        currentList2 = currentList.copy()
        currentList = list()

        for i in currentList2:
            if i in dependenciesNames:
                print(i, "already found")

            else:
                dependenciesNames.append(i)

                try:
                    fileInfo = importlib.machinery.PathFinder().find_spec(i)
                    print(fileInfo.origin)

                    dependenciesPaths.append(fileInfo.origin)

                    currentList.append(fileInfo.origin)

                except AttributeError as e:
                    print(e)
                    print(i)
                    print(importlib.machinery.PathFinder().find_spec(i))
                    # print(red, "Odd noneType import called ", i, " in path ", path, end, sep='')


        print("Found paths for imports in '" + path + "'")


        for fileInfo in currentList:
            main(fileInfo)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # args
    args = sys.argv
    print(args)

    if len(args) == 2:
        p = args[1]

    elif len(args) == 3:
        p = args[1]

        open(args[2], "a").close()
        sys.stdout = open(args[2], "w")

    else:
        print('Usage')
        print('PyDependencies <InputFile>')
        print('PyDependencies <InputFile> <OutputFile')

        sys.exit(2)

    if not os.path.exists(p):
        print(red, "Path '" + p + "' is not a real path", end, sep='')

    elif os.path.isdir(p):
        print(red, "Path '" + p + "' is a directory, not a file", end, sep='')

    elif "".join(pathlib.Path(p).suffixes) != ".py":
        print(red, "Path '" + p + "' is not a python file", end, sep='')

    else:
        print(green, "Path '" + p + "' is a valid python file", end, sep='')

        main(p)

    deps = set(dependenciesNames)

    print(deps)

    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Would you mind putting comments in your answer or in your code?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to help someone list all dependencies with versions from the Python script itself. This will list all dependencies in the user virtual environment.

```py
from pip._internal.operations import freeze

x = freeze.freeze()
for dependency in x:
   print(dependency)
```

for this you need to install `pip` as a dependency. Use the following command to install pip dependency.

```
pip install pip
```

The print output would look like the following.

```
certifi==2020.12.5
chardet==4.0.0
idna==2.10
numpy==1.20.3
oauthlib==3.1.0
pandas==1.2.4
pip==21.1.2
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
setuptools==41.2.0
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.26.4
```

Comment: this is equivalent to `pip freeze`. However it also demonstrates how to get the list of packages within a python list so may have applicability beyond using the shell commands specifically.