# Why doesn't Flask show in Pip Freeze from within virtualenv?

Tags: python, flask, pip

I'm having an issue where running `pip freeze` while in a virtual env on an Amazon EC2 instance does not show `flask`. However, if I run it outside of the virtual environment it installs just fine with the `--user` flag.

```
[ec2-user@ip-34-235-217-226 html]$ virtualenv venv
New python executable in /var/www/html/venv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in /var/www/html/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
[ec2-user@ip-34-235-217-226 html]$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) [ec2-user@ip-34-235-217-226 html]$ pip install flask
Collecting flask
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/72/b5ed853418364d8e7006550dbdb2cb9ac3e33ce3c9145acc7898fca8c0b6/Flask-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (6.7)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in ./venv/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (0.24)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from Jinja2>=2.10->flask)
Installing collected packages: flask, MarkupSafe
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.0 flask-1.0.1
```

But then I run `pip freeze` and flask is not in the list

```
(venv) [ec2-user@ip-34-235-217-226 html]$ pip freeze
click==6.7
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Now the crazy part is if I ran `pip install flask --user` and `pip freeze` outside of the virtual environment, it works just fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried `pipreqs`? check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237072/list-dependencies-in-python/42237244#42237244

Comment: very weird. can't reproduce.

Comment: @haifzhan I've just installed ``pipreqs`` and generated the requirements file. Unfortunately, when I run the project python file, I still get an error that the flask library is missing and it still does not show in ``pip freeze``.

Comment: I tried both `pipreqs` and `pip freeze`, can't reproduce your issue

Comment: I suggest there may be some kind of conflict between pip, virtualenv, and your operating system package manager (directory `dist-packages` inside venv seems strange). Could you provide some info about how had you installed python, pip and virtrualenv in your server?