# How to see what packages are required to install another package?

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, package

I want to install many packages on an offline computer, I download and install manually using the following code:

```
pip install XXXXX.whl --user
```

Although the code above does the offline installation, the package needs other packages so it tries to connect to the internet. I can see what package it is looking for. So, I will download manually and again install that. If there are a lot of packages required, it becomes overwhelming.

Any better solution? Can I know from the beginning that what packages have to be downloaded for installing my package?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170588/list-dependencies-of-python-wheel-file. The answer below the top one can help with an offline computer

Comment: Note that this ↑ will only show you first level dependencies - as in, direct dependencies of your particular package. Its dependencies can also have its own dependencies.

Honestly the most reliable thing you can do is to just install your package in a fresh venv on the online pc, then run `pip freeze` to see the list of all packages and their resolved versions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you use anaconda?
Make a conda environment on your online pc and install all your packages you need.

Then check with

'''
conda list
'''

What packages you need.