# .whl file generated by build doesn't include information about dependencies

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to create a Python package. I have a `setup.cfg` which contains this section:

```
install_requires =
    pyo>=1.0.4
    pywebview>=3.4
    strictyaml>=1.4.4
```

When I run `python3 -m build` in the project directory, I get a `dist/mypackage.whl` as expected. When I switch to another virtual environment to test installing it with `pip install mypackage.whl`, that works too; however, it doesn't install the dependencies. In fact, the dependencies aren't mentioned in the .whl file at all, as I tested this using

```
unzip -c mypackage.whl 'mypackage.dist-info/*' | grep pyo
```

which didn't bring anything up.

Is dependency information even supposed to be included in a wheel? [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50208939/13946974) would suggest so. If not, is this what `requirements.txt` is for?

**Edit:** Here's my full setup.cfg and packages version info:

```
[metadata]
name = mypackage
version = 0.1
author = David Husz
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
install_requires =
    pyo>=1.0.4
    pywebview>=3.4
    strictyaml>=1.4.4
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Operating System :: OS Independent

[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find:
include_package_data = True
python_requires = >=3.6

[options.packages.find]
where = src
```

My setuptools version is 57.4.0, and my build version is 0.5.1.

Comment: show your full setup.cfg, and show your setuptools version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`install_requires` is not a `[metadata]` setting but an `[options]` setting

move that down to the `[options]` section and you should be good to go!

here's an example from one of my projects: https://github.com/asottile/setup-cfg-fmt/blob/f7d50142cec2174daeee4a67cebf2d161c0cca46/setup.cfg#L25-L26