# is there a way to list all dependancies that being used for the specific project in Python

Tags: python, import, dependencies, requirements

I just have finished the project with Python. I need to add `requirements.txt`. Is there a way in a command line to list all the dependencies I have been using along with their versions?

I have researched but it looks like I need to go manually through every single one of them, I was wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: The _best_ way to do this is to add them as you go. Are you working in a virtual environment? `pip freeze > requirements.txt` should give you a starting point, but you may get a bunch of stuff there that you don't really need.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List dependencies in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237072/list-dependencies-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

to do that you need to type the following command `pip/pip3 freeze`

after that you can copy the dependencies into the `requirements.txt` file