# Are there any free libraries that can generate a program dependence graph (PDG) for a Python program?

Tags: python, static-analysis

I'm looking for a tool that can read a Python program and generate a program dependence graph of the program. Are there any free libraries that can do this?

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237072/list-dependencies-in-python?

Comment: https://github.com/rbanffy/pip-chill might be an option or place to start

Comment: Hey @AMG sorry I should have been clearer. I'm not looking for Python pip package dependencies. The PDG I'm referring to is like Fig 13 in this paper and it is used for static analysis: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS395T/2009fa/papers/ferrante87.pdf